# Parsing XML fro URL using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Have XML data like :

```
<List>
   <Data>
     <input1>1004519827</input1>
     <input2></input2>
   </Data>
   <Data>
     <input1>0214785698</input1>
     <input2></input2>
   </Data>
   <Data>
     <input1>1024589658</input1>
     <input2></input2>
   </Data>
</List>
```

Want parse `<inpute>this</inpute1>` . I am trying to parse from sql like :

```
 select @Url = 'http://myurl/myval.ashx?command=Cancel&from=25.10.2013&to=25.10.2013'

    Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT; 
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @Url, 'false' 
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send' 
    Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT      
    Exec sp_OADestroy @Object 

    Declare @XmlResponse as xml; 
    select @XmlResponse = CAST(@ResponseText as xml)  
    select @XmlResponse.value('(//List/Data/input1)[1]','varchar(50)')
```

But when i  execute procedure have an error : **illegal xml character**  . I reconfigured sp_configure to 1

Comment: Is this stored as an XML Blob (one record), or one record per XML line?

Comment: And what's the response? An XML or an error message?

Comment: There's no `<inpute>` tag in your sample XML, and your start tag `<inpute>` and end tag `</inpute1>` don't match.... what do you **really** want to parse??

Comment: @marc_s i want parse those numbers which are in  input1

Comment: Just the first occurrence, or all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XmlInput XML 

SET @XmlInput = '<List>
   <Data>
     <input1>1004519827</input1>
     <input2></input2>
   </Data>
   <Data>
     <input1>0214785698</input1>
     <input2></input2>
   </Data>
   <Data>
     <input1>1024589658</input1>
     <input2></input2>
   </Data>
</List>'

SELECT
    Input1 = XCol.value('(input1)[1]', 'bigint')
FROM
    @XmlInput.nodes('/List/Data') AS XList(XCol)
```

The `.nodes()` function will return a list of all matching XML elements (representing the `<Data>` XML elements), and then you can grab the `<input1>` value from those elements using the `.value()` XQuery method on them.

Comment: thank you it's work if i have in procedure xml file , but how it will be if I parse from url ?

Comment: @GeoVIP: you should not task SQL Server with downloading from a URL - that's a job for a business/service layer in whatever programming language you're using. Pass the resulting XML to SQL Server - that's where it's job starts!

Comment: (psst, not sure if you flagged to migrate [this steaming pile of dung](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19615856/27-ips-lcd-monitor?noredirect=1), but I think [superuser may put out a hit on you for it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203172/migrated-question-not-marked-as-migrated-on-source-site))